# How can I use multiple conditions within groupby and transform in dataframe with python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transform

I'd like to get a specific result in a new column (NewRank) conditionally and considering the groupby and operations.

Given this dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = {'User': ['User1', 'User2', 'User3', 'User4', 'User5', 'User6', 'User7','User8', 'User9', 'User10','User11', 'User12', 'User13','User14', 'User15', 'User16'],
        'Type': ['A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', float('nan'),'C','C','C','D','D','D','E','E','E'],
        'Usage': [100, 200, 150, 50, 75, 175, float('nan'),0,0,0,-3,-1,0,4,0,0],
        'OldRank': [3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, float('nan'),1,1,1,1,2,3,3,1,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

my expected results are the follow:

```
      User Type  Usage  OldRank  NewRank
0    User1    A  100.0      3.0      3.0
4    User5    A   75.0      2.0      2.0
3    User4    A   50.0      1.0      1.0
1    User2    B  200.0      3.0      3.0
5    User6    B  175.0      2.0      2.0
2    User3    B  150.0      1.0      1.0
7    User8    C    0.0      1.0      0.0
8    User9    C    0.0      1.0      0.0
9   User10    C    0.0      1.0      0.0
12  User13    D    0.0      3.0      3.0
11  User12    D   -1.0      2.0      2.0
10  User11    D   -3.0      1.0      1.0
13  User14    E    4.0      3.0      3.0
14  User15    E    0.0      1.0      0.0
15  User16    E    0.0      1.0      0.0
6    User7  NaN    NaN      NaN      NaN
```

This is my attempt, but it fails with an error:

```
df['NewRank'] = df.groupby('Type')['Usage'].transform(lambda x: 0 if ( ((x==0).all()) | ( (x.min()>=0) & (df['OldRank']==0) ) ) else df['OldRank'] )

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

A wanted result can be achieved with a different approach, but it is too long and requires adding additional columns which deteriorates the performance of the process. I believe there must be a shorter and better way to accomplish this:

```
# Long code:

df['R1'] = df.groupby('Type')['Usage'].transform(lambda x: (x==0).all() )
df['R2'] = df.groupby('Type')['Usage'].transform(lambda x: (x.min()>=0))
df['R3'] = df.groupby('Type')['Usage'].transform(lambda x: (x==0))

print(df)

df['NewRank'] = np.where((df['R2']==True) & (df['R3']==True) | df['R1']==True ,0, df['OldRank'])

df = df.sort_values(by=['Type', 'Usage'], ascending=[True, False])
print(df)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can try to split into 2 transforms to be more clear:

```
# if the 'Usage' column are 0 or NaN the 'NewRank' column is set to 0
# otherwise, the 'OldRank' column is used as the 'NewRank' column
df['NewRank'] = df.groupby('Type')['Usage'].transform(
    lambda x: 0 if ((x.isin([0, np.nan])).all()) else df['OldRank']
)

# apply a secondary condition to 'NewRank'
# if the minimum value in the 'Usage' column is non-negative and the 
# 'OldRank' column is 0, set 'NewRank' to 0
df['NewRank'] = np.where((df['Usage'].ge(0)) & (df['OldRank'].eq(0)), 0, df['NewRank'])
```

I hope this would help! Cheers

Comment: Thank you apnd for your prompt anwer. 
Unfortunately, the second statement does not work. Tt produces incorrect results specifically in group (Type E)  and does not respect the groupby. Where I'd like the .min() for the groupby to be assert.-
The answer in group E is: 3,1,1. It should be 3,0,0. In fact the condition was always true and takes the value from df['NewRank']

Comment: Thank you apnd for your prompt anwer. 
Unfortunately, the second statement does not work. It produces incorrect results specifically in group (Type E) and does not respect the groupby. The groupby.min() have to be asserted.-
The answer in group E is: 3,1,1. It should be 3,0,0. In fact the condition was always true and takes in all cases the value from df['NewRank']

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of 2 of the `.groupby` calls.

```
R1 = ~df['Type'].isin(df.loc[df['Usage'] != 0, 'Type'])
R2 = df.groupby('Type')['Usage'].transform('min') >= 0
R3 = df['Usage'] == 0
```

You also don't need the `== True` comparisons, you already have the booleans.

```
df['NewRank'] = np.where(R1 | (R2 & R3), 0, df['OldRank'])
```

```
>>> df.sort_values(by=['Type', 'Usage'], ascending=[True, False])
      User Type  Usage  OldRank  NewRank
0    User1    A  100.0      3.0      3.0
4    User5    A   75.0      2.0      2.0
3    User4    A   50.0      1.0      1.0
1    User2    B  200.0      3.0      3.0
5    User6    B  175.0      2.0      2.0
2    User3    B  150.0      1.0      1.0
7    User8    C    0.0      1.0      0.0
8    User9    C    0.0      1.0      0.0
9   User10    C    0.0      1.0      0.0
12  User13    D    0.0      3.0      3.0
11  User12    D   -1.0      2.0      2.0
10  User11    D   -3.0      1.0      1.0
13  User14    E    4.0      3.0      3.0
14  User15    E    0.0      1.0      0.0
15  User16    E    0.0      1.0      0.0
6    User7  NaN    NaN      NaN      NaN
```

Comment: Hi jqurious, your code is much cleaner and it works. 
I dont understand too well the definition of R1, it search within the group if all are !=0, but what about if my groupby were two columns [TypeA] and [TypeB] instead of only [Type]?
Thank you so much

Comment: `~df[['TypeA', 'TypeB']].isin(df.loc[df['Usage'] != 0, ['TypeA', 'TypeB']]).all(axis=1)` - you break it into parts, `df['Usage'] != 0` finds all the non-zero rows. You then test if your group columns `.isin` this result, meaning, there is a non-zero value in the group. You then use `~` to invert the result, which will leave you with only all-zero groups.